# sideMenu not displayed after login

Tags: ios, swift, side-menu

I have included [kukushi](https://github.com/kukushi/SideMenu) side menu. I have done things according to the documentation. The screen shot with the codes in app delegate are below:

```
    func setUpHomeVC() {
    var window: UIWindow?

    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Dashboard", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let contentViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DashboardViewController") as! DashboardViewController
    let menuViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuViewCOntroller") as! MenuViewCOntroller
    SideMenuController.preferences.basic.menuWidth = 240
    SideMenuController.preferences.basic.statusBarBehavior = .hideOnMenu
    SideMenuController.preferences.basic.position = .sideBySide
    SideMenuController.preferences.basic.direction = .left
    SideMenuController.preferences.basic.enablePanGesture = true
    SideMenuController.preferences.basic.supportedOrientations = .portrait
    SideMenuController.preferences.basic.shouldRespectLanguageDirection = true
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = SideMenuController(contentViewController: contentViewController,
        menuViewController: menuViewController)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    setUpHomeVC()
    return true
}
```

[image]
 The identifier, class and module has been added according to the documentation. After login there is dashboard which consist of menu button. On login the code is:

```
 private func goToDashboard() {
    let dashboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Dashboard", bundle: nil)
    let navView = dashboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "DashboardViewController") as DashboardViewController
    present(navView,animated: false)

}
```

On dashboard there is a button which have click event:

```
  @IBAction func btnMenuClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Menu button has been clicked")
    self.sideMenuController?.revealMenu(animated: true)
}
```

when I click on that button the print function is called but the menu is not revealed.

Can anyone explain it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you presenting DashboardViewController?

Comment: Dashboard contains the button that triggers the menu

Comment: Can you try by pushing the DashboardViewController on goToDashboard() on login and check...?

Comment: self.navigationController?.pushViewController(navView, animated: false)
You mean this?
Login view controller and DashboardView controller are in different storyboard

Comment: it's not working, I can't even navigate tge view

Comment: try to check all segue names are correct as defined in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup your appDelegate like this,

```
  func setUpHomeVC() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Your Login Storyboard", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC")
    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
}

   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    setUpHomeVC()
    return true
}
```

And in your login event:

```
    private func goToDashboard() {
    self.pushVC()

}

private func pushVC()  {
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Dashboard", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let contentViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DashboardViewController") as! DashboardViewController
    let menuViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuViewCOntroller") as! MenuViewCOntroller
    SideMenuController.preferences.basic.menuWidth = 240
    SideMenuController.preferences.basic.statusBarBehavior = .hideOnMenu
    SideMenuController.preferences.basic.position = .sideBySide
    SideMenuController.preferences.basic.direction = .left
    SideMenuController.preferences.basic.enablePanGesture = true
    SideMenuController.preferences.basic.supportedOrientations = .portrait
    SideMenuController.preferences.basic.shouldRespectLanguageDirection = true
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = SideMenuController(contentViewController: contentViewController,
                                                    menuViewController: menuViewController)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DashboardVC should be in a navigation controller for sidemenu to present. Try pushing the controller instead of presenting it.If you have the controller in a different storyboard, you can use this function:

```
  func pushVC(storyboardName : String, vcname : String)  {
        let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: storyboardName, bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcname)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

Also, I would suggest you learn about when to push, present, and make root view controllers as all serve different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I think your current implementation is wrong. The problem is we need to implement and push the view controllers as SideMenuControllers bundle, not separate ViewControlers

If you want to have the side menu after login, then set your login page first in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Then you can call setUpHomeVC from your loginVC.